# Некорректное отображение комментариев коммита на русском языке в GIT

Tags: python, git, cmd, pycharm

Что нужно сделать для нормального отображения комментариев на русском языке? Если дело в кодировке...Кодировке Гита или командной строки? Где изменить? Заранее большое спасибо за помощь[image: ![]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNzuc.jpg)

Comment: ```chcp 65001```

Comment: Тоже не помогло!

Comment: Почему в тегах стоит pycharm, если скриншот не из него?

Comment: это скриншот ИМЕННО из PyCharm! Даже кусок уведомления справа внизу для тех,кто сомневается)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение в статье 2009 года...[Хабр](https://habr.com/ru/post/74839/)
Для меня сработало следующее:
1. В локальном конфиге в секцию [core] добавил quotepath = false и добавил секцию [i18n] с commitencoding = cp1251 и logoutputencoding = cp866
2. После этого установил в командной строке SET LESSCHARSET=utf-8

Все помогло!
По отдельности каждая из операций проблему не решала!
Но прописывать LESSCHARSET приходиться при каждом запуске.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тому, что у вас каждый второй символ имеет код D0 или D1 - это русский текст в кодировке UTF-8, что для git является нормой. Значит проблема с кодировкой консоли, которая, судя по всему, не хочет отображать ничего кроме ASCII.

UPD

Судя по скриншоту, вы используете git for windows. Он в своб очередь использует утилиту less. Ей можно указать кодировку установкой переменной окружения `LESSCHARSET`

```
SET LESSCHARSET=utf-8
```

На моей машине после этого `git log` стал показывать русский текст в консоли.

Comment: К сожалению не помогло.